# linear-gradient (rgba) not working in Safari on iPhone

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My gradient is not working in Safari on iPhone. Is there a webkit to add on for different browsers? When I remove the gradient my image appears on iPhone.

```css
.serv-bg {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(17, 28, 36), rgba(119, 201, 212, .1)), url(/images/service-main.jpg) no-repeat center center /cover;
  border-left: 10px solid white !important;
  border-top: 10px solid white !important;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white !important;
  border-right: 5px solid white !important;
  height: 70vh;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient and https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients is your go to pages to check compatibility. and I would imagine that image will be the first before the linear-gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might work if you add `-webkit` and `-image` to your CSS:

```css
.serv-bg {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(17, 28, 36), rgba(119, 201, 212, .1)), url(/images/service-main.jpg) no-repeat center center /cover;
  border-left: 10px solid white !important;
  border-top: 10px solid white !important;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white !important;
  border-right: 5px solid white !important;
  height: 70vh;
}
```